# Fortran output of real number

Tags: fortran, output

have declared a variable:

real*4 FACTOR

and then FACTOR=2.25

I want to output 2.25

Tried F3.2

Any help?

```
WRITE (lu09,9315)FACTOR

9315 FORMAT (F4.2)
```

Comment: What happened with what you tried?  Can't tell why this is insufficient.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, please forgive me for being such an idiot and I'll forgive you for treating me like one.   - simple code has been added to the question.  My output is .02.

Comment: What output is there from the revised code?

Comment: I believe your information is correct, @wallyk.  I think there is another problem in my program for if I write to std out, it displays as 2.25 as it should using your answer.  I'd like to thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fortran format `F3.2` would output numbers up to `.99`, but anything larger won't fit.  If you mean you want 3 digits before the decimal, change it to `F6.2`.

The first format number is the total field width, including the decimal and fractional digits.

For 2.25 to appear, the format width must be at least 4:  `F4.2`

Comment: I changed it to F4.2 and also tried F5.2, but my output is .02. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @KathyB.:  I put what I could figure out from your comments into the question, but it is *far* too complicated to debug.  Please try a simple `format` with a simple `write` with only **one** variable.

Comment: @wallyk I have simplified the code and added to the question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The f0.2 format gives the desired output, as demonstrated below. It writes the number with two digits after the decimal point and as many digits before the decimal point as needed.

```
program xwrite
implicit none
real*4 :: factor = 2.25
write (*,"(f0.2)") factor
end program xwrite
! output:
! 2.25
```